# Resetting printing password

Tags: macos, password, printing

I use a printer on a Windows server configured as

```
smb://server.domain/printer
```

as it requires authentication after the first use I had to give my credentials which where then stored in the key chain.

So far so good.

I then had to change my password on the server side. Now OS X refuses to print telling me "Hold for Authentication"

[image: Printer status]

With `lpq` I see:

```
stbh is ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     corti   483     Printer Status                  1024 bytes
2nd     corti   484     Printer Status                  1024 bytes
3rd     corti   485     Microsoft Word - ************ 371712 bytes
```

In `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
E [03/Feb/2015:07:43:53 +0100] [Job 483] Unable to support AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED
E [03/Feb/2015:07:43:57 +0100] [Job 483] Authentication required
E [03/Feb/2015:07:43:58 +0100] [Job 484] Unable to support AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED
E [03/Feb/2015:07:44:00 +0100] [Job 484] Authentication required
E [03/Feb/2015:07:44:02 +0100] [Job 485] Authentication required
```

I deleted the stored password in Key Chain, deleted the job and tried again but I still don't get the dialog asking me for the new password.

Any idea on how to force a new authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Press the refresh icon to the far right of the print job.  This should bring up the dialogue for your credentials, supply these and then make sure to check the box to save them to your keychain and then it will pass this through for any subsequent print jobs.